# CSqlDataProvider : How to escape strings for database queries Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm using CSqlDataProvider to get the data. I do construct the query on my own.

How do I escape string while constructing mysql queries?

I tried to use `mysql_real_escape_string` but it does not work

```
$count=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($this->constructCountQuery())->queryScalar();      
        return $dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider($this->constructDataQuery(), array(
            'totalItemCount'=>$count,
            'sort'=>array(
                'attributes'=>array(
                      'clinic_name', 'doctor_name','country'
                ),
            ),
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>10,
            ),

        ));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use named parametes and use the [`params`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider#params-detail) property to specify the parameters. Yii's PDO will aitomatically esacape the string

For example

```
$dataProvider = new CSqlDataProvider('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `title`=:title', array(
            'totalItemCount'=>$count,
            'params'=>array(
                   ':title'=>$title,
            ),
            'sort'=>array(
                'attributes'=>array(
                      'clinic_name', 'doctor_name','country'
                ),
            ),
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=>10,
            ),

        ));
```